# How to use mailto function in iBooks HTML Widget

Tags: email, ibooks

I have tried code with the mailto function in a web browser on my iPad which links to the mail app, but the same code does not work in the iBooks (the mailto does absolutely nothing in the iBooks app).

Does anyone know of some sort of workaround for emailing out html form data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to link inside an iBooks page, open your link inspector and the "Link to" menu should have an email option.

If you are using the HTML widget option, you could try something like this:
Open Email